# Is there an authentic source for the hadith where the Prophet and Ali ibn Abi Talib joke about eating dates?

Tags: hadith, source-identification, food

On another page, where the question asks if the Prophet Muhammad (SAW) used humour in his daily life, one user gave a very nice answer, but I wanted to clarify something:
The date incident that has been used as an example in the user's answer, is it a hadith or from the See-rah? And is it possible for anyone to find me an authentic source of this information?

The date seed incident, as quoted from [this answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/560/22), is as follows:

> One incident I remember is when the Prophet (saws) was with Ali ibn
>   Abi Talib (ra) and they had a dozen dates. As they were about to
>   finish, Ali (ra) saw some people approaching. He quickly moved the
>   pile of 6 pits that he had to the Prophet (saws)'s pile and jocularly
>   told the passersby that the Prophet (saws) had kept all the dates to
>   himself and didn't share! The Prophet (saws) in good spirits said
>   right back: Look at Ali, he eats the dates and he eats the pits as
>   well! (because he didn't have any pits on his side).

This is the page on which I found that answer:

[Did the Prophet Muhammad (saws) use humor with those around him?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/555/did-the-prophet-muhammad-saws-use-humor-with-those-around-him)

I would be very grateful if someone could help me with this. Thanks :)

Comment: I checked sunnah.com and couldn't find any reference to this hadith. Did you try Google? Maybe some you can find another site that reports it with the source.

Answer (score 2):

Shia Muslims have a similar Hadeeth but with small distinctions such that neither the holy prophet nor Imam Ali --peace be upon them-- lie during their conservation (*the lies in the cited Hadeeth: `the Prophet (saws) had kept all the dates to himself and didn't share!` and `Look at Ali, he eats the dates and he eats the pits as well`*). Shia version is as follows:

> في كتاب (زهر الربيع) «انّ رسول اللّه صلّى اللّه عليه و آله كان يأكل
>   رطبا مع أمير المؤمنين عليه السّلام، و كان يضع النّوى قدام أمير
>   المؤمنين عليه السّلام و هو لا يلتفت، فلمّا فرغا، كان النوى كله في
>   الطرف الذي يأكل فيه أمير المؤمنين عليه السّلام، فقال له رسول اللّه
>   صلّى اللّه عليه و آله: «يا على! انك لأكول؟» فقال على عليه السّلام: «يا
>   رسول اللّه! الأكول الذي يأكل التمر و نواه» فتبسّم رسول اللّه صلّى
>   اللّه عليه و آله. هكذا نقله جدّنا الأعلى، و لم يذكر له مدركا، لكنّنا
>   لمّا كنّا في مقام البحث و التنقيب عند تسطير هذه السطور، وجدناه مع
>   تفصيل أكثر، و هو على ما يلي، لكنّ النقل بالمعنى، لأنّ الكتاب الذي
>   نقلنا منه (كوكب درّى في فضائل علي عليه السّلام) بالأردوية، و هو هذا:
>   نقل في كتاب (لطائف الطوائف) أنه ورد في روايات عديدة: أنّ رسول اللّه
>   صلّى اللّه عليه و آله كان يأكل التمر يوما مع أصحابه، و كان يضع النوى
>   قدام على عليه السّلام مزاحا و كانت الأصحاب أيضا كذلك يفعلون باشارته
>   صلّى اللّه عليه و آله. فلمّا فرغوا من الأكل، سأل رسول اللّه صلّى اللّه
>   عليه و آله مخاطبا الى أصحابه: «من الأكول فيما بينكم؟». فقالوا: «يا
>   رسول اللّه! من كثرت نواه فهو أكول». فأجاب علي عليه السّلام فورا: «من
>   أكل التمر مع النوى فهو أكول». فقال رسول اللّه صلّى اللّه عليه و آله:
>   «ان أخي على بن أبي طالب غالب غير مغلوب، لأنني مدينة العلم و علي بابها»
>
> source: سید نعمت الله جزایری، کشف الأسرار في شرح الإستبصار، ج1، ص: 165
>
> ... The holy prophet --peace be upon him and his household-- was
>   eating dates together with a number of his companions (including Imam
>   Ali --peace be upon him--) and was putting his pits in front of Imam
>   Ali --peace be upon him-- and was inspiring to his companions to do
>   the same puuting their pits in front of him, kidding. When they
>   finished eating the holy prophet --peace be upon him and his
>   household-- asked his companions "who is the most eater among you?"
>   They answered "Oh apostle of Allah! one whose pits are more he is the
>   most eater!" [*see no lie is stated here*], Imam Ali --peace be upon
>   him-- instantaneously answered back "whoever eats dates with their
>   pits is the most eater!". [*again note the word "whoever" which
>   survives the statement from being a lie*] The holy prophet --peace be
>   upon him and his family-- then said: "it is true and noway false that
>   my brother Ali ibn AbiTaleb is a winner never defeated, as I am the
>   city of knwoledge and Ali is its gate."

Actually AFAIK this Hadeeth is not a very strongly authentic one due to Sanad, however, as the Hadeeth contains no religious rule and is not disrespectful as well (but even wise and respectful) it might be acceptable.